# Automated tests using IndexedDB in a create-react-app

Tags: automated-tests, create-react-app, indexeddb

I'm re-implementing an old web app using create-react-app.  The app is based around IndexedDB.  create-react-app runs tests in Node.js, which does not have IndexedDB, so tests which access the DB will fail.

Should I `eject` and run tests in headless Chrome, or is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

[fake-indexeddb](https://github.com/dumbmatter/fakeIndexedDB) implements almost all of the IndexedDB API in memory, so it can be used with Node.js

(To import it using ES modules, use `import auto from "fake-indexeddb/auto.js";`)